# mongoose - select specific fields in Model.create

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
 const generatedEvent = await Event.create(req.body);
 res.send(generatedEvent);
```

I am getting some data from the request body and I can generate a new Event. And I'm returning the event to client when it has generated. But I don't want to return all fields with event. I want to make filter operation like how we are using select function like this: `Event.find().select({title:1,description:1})`
How can i use this select func with Model.create?

Comment: this create function cannot specific the return fields, so u want to return specific fields like this res.send({ title: generatedEvent.title });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [mongoose-source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L3008), you can see that `Model.create` returns a promise with the created/inserted documents. There's no way to specify a filtering-options to return only specific fields.

Of course you could do a `.find()` in combination with a `.select()` call after creating/inserting a new record but that would result in one extra DB-query for each insert which does not make a lot of sense.

You could instead just return the desired properties from the returned document, since you know that a new document was inserted successfully with the provided data, when the promise resolved. So you could simply do:

```
res.send({title: generatedEvent.title, description: generatedEvent.description});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Model.create()` internally doesn't fetch the document from the database, rather it actually returns the result whether it's inserted successfully or not. If successful, `mongoose` will return the original mongoose document that mongoose created before sending to the database.

So you could just select the fields by yourself. Using es2015 [Object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Object shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) would help writing more concise code.

```js
const { title, description } = await Event.create(req.body); // Object destructuring
res.send({ title, description }); // Object shorthand property names
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, "projection" may not be done with `create`, but once `create` has returned the new document, the `delete` keyword may be used for removing arbitrary fields. **There's just one gotcha though**, `delete` does not work on Mongoose document objects, because their properties are configured in a way that they are not deleteable (*if you're curious how this is done, read this [link](https://javascript.info/object-properties)*).

Fortunately, however, Mongoose provides a [`toObject()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.toObject()) method, that could turn Mongoose document objects into plain Javascript objects. Using that, the `delete` keyword must work too, so any fields (properties) could be deleted. E.g.:

```
const doc = await Doc.create(req.body);
const _doc = doc.toObject();
delete _doc._id;
delete _doc.isTrashed;
// etc.
```