# Express - How to exclude a field from the response returned by Model.findOne() and Model.create() mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to exclude the user's password field when sending a response to my front end. of course, I don't want anyone to access the user's encrypted password.

I have looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257063/mongoose-select-specific-fields-in-model-create), but the solution does not look good for models with many fields.

I'm using `.select('-password')` with `Model.find()`, `Model.findById()`, and `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()`

but It's not working for `Model.findOne()` and `Model.create()`

How can I exclude some fields when returning a response ?

```
/**
 * @desc   Authenticate User
 * @route  /api/acccounts/signin
 * @access Public
 */
export const authenticateUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const values = await loginSchema.validateAsync(req.body);

  const { email, password, rememberMe } = values;

  const account = await Account.findOne({ email });

  if (account && (await account.matchPassword(password))) {
    return res.json({
      id: account.id,
      firstName: account.firstName,
      lastName: account.lastName,
      email: account.email,
      isAdmin: account.isAdmin,
      ...other fields,
      token: generateToken(account.id, rememberMe),
    });
  }

  return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid email or password' });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use projection to exclude the field in your response like this

```
db.collection.findOne({
  email: "sample@sample.com"
},
{
  password: 0
})
```

Here is like of playground to test it: [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e-G94muGIGa)

For more details check out [findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) official documentation